# Request/Response pattern over BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a service running on local network over HTTP. The interface is the classic request/response where data can go both ways. My task is to convert this service to use BLE (bluetooth low energy).

I am looking for a way to send a request with some data, then receive a response with some other data. So far I only found a way to either read a characteristic without sending data, or write a characteristic without getting anything back.

Is there a way to achieve what I want or do I have to change my interface to adapt to BLE limitations? E.g. I could write a characteristic, then do a separate read to simulate a request/response.

Comment: This is often done with service that exposes two characteristics: one for transmitting and one for receiving (as seen from the peer). For example: https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-adafruit-bluefruit-le-uart-friend/uart-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to solve this is to have one characteristic you perform "Write Without Response" on and another characteristic where the remote device sends "Notifications" on.

You can also use L2CAP CoC instead of GATT if that suits you better.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with Emil's answer (with notifications) is that this will be broadcasted to all clients. At least that's what happen on ESP32 using Arduino. Idk if on other platforms the notifcation can be send to a single client.

Comment: This is because the idea of several "apps" that are multiplexed on a single GATT client is an afterthought. In the BLE standard, the concept of having several "apps" does not exist. Instead there is just one single GATT client running on each device. L2CAP CoC naturally solves this though. Another solution (if using GATT notifications) is to for example use the first byte as identifier which app should inspect this notification. If you instead mean client as different connected devices, then the standard doesn't really enforce that the same value must be broadcasted to every client.